# .NET BLAZOR - No reaction on ValueChanged event

Tags: c#, .net, blazor

I have some problem with  markup from blazor:

My example of code:

```
                    <InputSelect id="Projects" class="form-control"
                                 ValueExpression="@(() => MenuViewModel.ProjectId)"
                                 Value="@MenuViewModel.ProjectId"
                                 ValueChanged="@((string value) => OnProjectChange(value))">

                        @foreach (var project in MenuViewModel.ListOfProjects)
                        {
                            <option value="@project.Value">@project.Text</option>
                        }
                    </InputSelect>`

    public void OnProjectChange(string value)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            MenuViewModel.ProjectId = value;
            MenuViewModel.ScriptId = "";
        }

        MenuViewModel.ListOfScripts = DropdownService.ListOfScripts(Convert.ToInt32(MenuViewModel.ProjectId));
        this.StateHasChanged();
    }
```

And problem is, the method OnProjectChange isn't called on value changed in that select menu.

To be more specific -> I built my solution based on this https://tutexchange.com/blazor-playground-series-part-6-how-to-create-cascading-dropdown-list-in-blazor/

but I want to render .blazor file in my cshtml view and I did that:

> @(await
> Html.RenderComponentAsync<MyApp.Views.Shared.Components.DropdownMenu>(RenderMode.ServerPrerendered))

Comment: Where is the code for OnProjectChange

Comment: added, i though its not needed in that case, because the method in any way isn't called

Comment: No repro. Try to make a more complete and simpler [mre].

Comment: I added more information, maybe now it helps to repro this issue

Comment: I've never seen `Html.RenderComponentAsync` in a normal blazor project. Which type of project template are you using?

Comment: For me it looks like the Blazor HUB is not being loaded.

Comment: I'm using .Net MVC and I would to add blazor component but probably in that is problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the worst part in my solution was trying to use .NET MVC project with blazor features. Finally I did in old good jquery. I didn't find another solution than switch to full blazor project in that case. I think we can close that issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I believe the recommended way to do this is to bind that value to a getter/setter and have the setter do your work or call your method (OnProjectChange).

I'm currently on my phone, but I'll try to include some code fragments off the top of my head to help point in the right direction.  So, your InputSelect tag might look something like this:

```
<InputSelect id="Projects" @bind-Value="this.ProjectId" ...{other stuff}... >
```

Then you would have a getter/setter for ProjectId that is something like this:

```
private string _projectId;
public string ProjectId {
    get { return (_projectId); }
    set {
        _projectId = value;
        OnProjectChange(value);
    }
}
```